# Which predefined roles should be assigned to the Google Cloud Run service to be able to read/write Firestore DB?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run

The closest roles that I could find are those of datastore and not firestore.

Comment: firestore is considered the next generation of datastore. in this case you can use `https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#datastore.user` for read/write access to firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Firestore` is considered the [next generation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore) of `Datastore`.

In this case you can use [**`roles/datastore.user`**..[GCP-iam-docs]](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#datastore.user) for read/write access to `Firestore`.